# CharAt(0) out of bounds exception when I have too much white space

Tags: java

Currently stuck on an assignment that requires me to print out the users name as such: Last,First Initial.
(Bob, Billy H.) If I add too many spaces between the first and middle name when inputting, I get an index out of bounds exception. (String out of bounds 0) The program runs completely fine unless I have more than one space between the first and middle name.

I can only use the trim, indexOf, substring,and charAt methods in this program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your name in this format: <spaces>First name<spaces>Middle name<spaces>Last name<spaces>");

    String name = s.nextLine();

    name = name.trim();

    String first, middle, last;

    int firstSpace = name.indexOf(' ');

    first = name.substring(0, firstSpace);

    int secondSpace = name.indexOf(" ", (firstSpace + 1));

    middle = name.substring((firstSpace + 1), secondSpace);

    middle.trim();

    last = name.substring(secondSpace+1);

    char middleInitial = middle.charAt(0);
    String initial = "";
    initial = initial + middleInitial;

    for(int i = 1; i < middle.length(); i++) {
        char currentLetter = middle.charAt(i);
        char lastLetter = middle.charAt(i - 1);

        if(lastLetter == ' ') {
            initial = initial + "." + currentLetter;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(last + "," + first + ' ' + initial + ".");

}

}
```

Comment: on which line does it fail?

Comment: Did you try debugging for the problem?

Comment: when you have multiple spaces there, your `secondSpace` is before the middle name, and not after as you would expect

Comment: and you are ignoring the result of `middle.trim();`.. change it to `middle = middle.trim();`

Comment: Look at `middle = name.substring((firstSpace + 1), secondSpace);`. `middle` will be empty if `secondSpace == fristSpace + 1`

Comment: do `name = name.replaceAll(" +", " ");` to replace all two or more white spaces.

Comment: It fails when I have more than one space between the first and middle name during input, and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error is for input

> ```
>    amid     skum    asdf
> ```

for above input:

```
int firstSpace = name.indexOf(' '); //firstSpace = 0
int secondSpace = name.indexOf(" ", (firstSpace + 1));//secondSpace = 1
 middle = name.substring((firstSpace + 1), secondSpace); // as the two or more continues space inputted, this will select empty string as firstSpace + 1 == secondSpace and later causing the exception
```

Do `name = name.replaceAll(" +", " ");` to replace all two or more white spaces.
As karthik suggested in comments, perform assignment `middle = middle.trim();`.

**EDIT:**
Since you can not use `replaceAll`, Modified the code just by using `trim` method. Have a closer look at the below snippets:

```
 String middleNameLastName = name.substring(firstSpace+1).trim();
 last = middleNameLastName.substring(index+1).trim();
```

These removes trailing spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Post1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name in this format: <spaces>First name<spaces>Middle name<spaces>Last name<spaces>");

        String name = s.nextLine();

        name = name.trim();
        String first, middle, last;
        int firstSpace = name.indexOf(' ');
        first = name.substring(0, firstSpace);
        String middleNameLastName = name.substring(firstSpace+1).trim();
        int index = middleNameLastName.indexOf(" ");
        middle = middleNameLastName.substring(0, index);
        last = middleNameLastName.substring(index+1).trim();

        System.out.println(last + "," + first + ' ' + middle.charAt(0) + ".");
        s.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would have used replaceAll if I was able to, but the assignment only allows me to use the four string methods that I stated above, and replaceAll is unfortunately not one of them.

Comment: I see. Missed that.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem without using replaceAll, I've tried everything and cannot solve this problem.

Comment: @Calculation Edited answer as per your comments